# Is a text message legally binding?

Tags: contract-law, binding

I was interested in purchasing a puppy from my job. I told my manager(A) that I didn’t have the money out right to afford it because of the whole corona situation, but the future puppies that I would sell and my paychecks will go fully to the dog till he’s paid off.

She said "of course, absolutely", and that whatever I don’t get financed for we can do in-house payments.

I had to ask my other manager(B) to help me with financing, who then said that I need to put a down payment of $2000, which that wasn't the agreement with manager A.

So I went to manager A and told her that that’s not the agreement we had, and I went into contacts on how the manager that told me it was $2000 failed to trai. me in certain positions in my job and she took some of my commission and the manager that made the agreement with me.

Comment: Hello, Kae, and welcome to law.stackexchange. I recommend that as a new user you take the [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour), as we are a little different from other forum sites. I found your question a little hard to parse, so I took the liberty of editing it to hopefully make it easier to follow, as clearer questions tend to attract better answers. While I have endeavored to not change the meaning of any part of your question, if you feel that I have done so, please by all means use the "Edit" button to make whatever further changes you see fit.

Comment: Also, I still do not see how a text message comes into play in this scenario?

Comment: $2000 down payment?  How much is the dog?! Even if the text message constitutes a binding agreement (doubtful), you would need a lawyer to try to enforce it - and it doesn't sound like you could afford to do that?

Comment: my mom can afford a lawyer for me I was the one who wanted to do the monthly payments for the dog. that had nothing to do with my mom Manager A said It was fine for me to in house whatever I dont get financed for. and then as soon as manager b said now I need a $2000 down payment and I went to manager A and was like how is that so that was never apart of the agreement and when I said wait you guys actually cheated me out of my commission and I never said anything and now your trying to cheat me out of a dog that doesnt even cost this much

Comment: Hi Kae, I would respectfully suggest that, when seeking info in a public forum and particularly when divulging certain details of a specific event, that you be careful about revealing your identity by not using your real name and/or a photo of yourself.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

> Is a text message legally binding?

Yes, but the terms of the message need to be clear enough to ascertain the parties' intent at the formation of that contract or agreement.

A contract does not even need to be in writing. There are also *oral* contracts and *implied* contracts, the latter referring to contracts which are inferred from the parties' conduct. A contract such as the agreement you describe here is binding regardless of its form. It is just easier to prove the existence of a contract if it is in writing.

You did not specify your jurisdiction. If it is in the US, the price tag --rather than the downpayment-- of the object of the contract (i.e., the puppy you intend to buy) determines whether your complaint would need to be filed in Small Claims court. Generally speaking, parties to a dispute in Small Claims court have to represent themselves.

Two remarks are pertinent. First, developing writing skills is utmost important not only for litigating a dispute, but also during the process of formulating the terms and conditions of a contract/agreement. [Your post](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/52281/1) indicates that you seriously need to work on that.

Second, the end of your post reflects that one of your managers violated labor law(s), which to most of us would be more worrisome than the controversy about the puppy. Legislation in most or all jurisdictions outlaws the act of withholding an employee's compensation regardless of its form (salary, commissions, and so forth). You might want to gain acquaintance with the labor laws of your jurisdiction so you can assess whether or how to proceed (does legislation require the employee to "exhaust administrative remedies" prior to filing in court? are administrative remedies optional? do these exist at all?), even if only to ascertain whether the deadline for filing the corresponding claim has elapsed.

Comment: I would have to show the text messages but manger A and myself were on the same page about in house financing the dog we were clear and both agreed and then manager B who knew nothing about this agreement between manger A and I, she threw in a $2000 down payment for the dog and I went to manager A and was like this wasnt apart of the agreement and I brought up you guys cheat me out of my money all the time and now you want to jack the price up on this dog and apparently she took offense to what I said and reneged the deal. Can she do that?

Comment: @KaeHartfield "*Can she do that?*" No. The text messages you had with manager A are binding, as explained in the answer.

Comment: she called the police and reported It as theft which It was not Manager B escorted me out of my workplace with the dog and both managers knew my intentions of buying the dog. When they tried to cheat me out of my money thats when Manager A tried to take back the agreement. It is in text of her making a clear agreement of how I would pay for the dog now we have to take this to civil court